# python facebook-sdk when i post then ''facebook.GraphAPIError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str."

Tags: python, python-3.4, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use python3.4

facebook-sdk version is 0.4

```
graph = GraphAPI("my access token")
profile = graph.get_object("me")
print(profile)
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
print(friends)
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

Then:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: How are you getting the access token? In the code (https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook/__init__.py) they indicate it can be done using `user = get_user_from_cookie(request.cookies, key, secret)` and then `user["access_token"]`. Is that how you're doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
gettoken = get_app_access_token("3808XXXXXXXX", "f8886b23167ca43XXXXXXXXXXX")
```

this is how i get access token
but

i went to this website

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/380896645420612/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2

there have a another type by access token

it 's look like :

CAAFabGkZCFkQBAFR363qZAFn2PBxPfgDMxeHQhYN1u5lE69juqeShVnSnsJrspF0EAiVKaMSn5fTquts4aFdw35gF0hxDKZArTDZCwETA4LqrmD3vdZCpT3Qgbebzay2XevkNmSsrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

have any diffrent?

one is app_token

the other is access token

so confuse